# Travelling to Germany while my wife is there working, can I use a tourist visa?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, applications, filipino-citizens

Last year I went to a Schengen state on a tourist visa and we are only girlfriend and boyfriend at that time, now this year, we just got married and I want to travel back to the Schengen state for a tour as well as to visit my wife.

Can I still apply for a tourist visa? Or it is mandatory now to take the visitor visa since she is already my wife? Because if I do apply for a visitor visa, my wife is still not updating her maiden name from all over the documents she got.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Association_with_shouting

Comment: What is your citizenship? By ‘tourist visa’ do you mean visa-free entry? I don’t understand the distinction you’re making between a tourist and a visit visa.

Comment: I came from Philippines. I mean on which type of Visa now should I apply since I am planning to take a Schengen Tourist Visa in the same country. Because last year me and my wife are not yet married, but now we are officially married, 4 months ago. Now the problem, if im going to take a visit visa, her marital status as of the moment are not yet updated in the country where she was residing. Now my question can I still go and apply for a Schengen tourist visa even if I have a wife on that country I am applying?

Comment: You’d have to select ‘Visit family or friends’ since that’s the main purpose of your trip. But that would be the choice irrespective of whether you’re married or not, if your partner is already living there and you were going to visit them.

Comment: Is your wife an EU national?

Comment: Yes, indeed that is also the suggestion they gave to me to take visit visa. Thank you so much for clarification. No she is not an EU national.

Answer (score 1):

You should apply for C-Visa, which is a visitor's visa

- the reason is to visit your wife and tourism and then to return

---

If you want to move permanently to your wife, you must apply for a D-Visa

- depending on whether she a EU Citizen or not the form of the application is different